generate_preset_pass_manager and Sampler API usage in IBM-Qiskit
I am trying to migrate my code to the latest version of qiskit>=1.0. Below is the sample code I made using the qiskit-ibm-runtime package.
Although the code is hopefully working fine, it has two run, which is kind of strange. Also, there is something new called a sampler. Is this sampler the same as backend.run in previous versions? Also, there is something new called generate_preset_pass_manager. Is this same as transpile in previous versions? The code is as below:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, assemble
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
# https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-runtime
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, SamplerV2 as Sampler

# Save an IBM Cloud account.
QiskitRuntimeService.save_account(channel="ibm_quantum", token="Add_your_key", overwrite=True)


# Read default credentials from disk
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel = 'ibm_quantum', instance="ibm-q/open/main")

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.measure_all()
print(qc.draw())

# Optimize problem for quantum execution
backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False)
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=1)
isa_circuit = pm.run(qc)

sampler = Sampler(mode=backend)
sampler.options.default_shots = 100000
job = sampler.run([isa_circuit])
print(f"Job ID is {job.job_id()}")
pub_result = job.result()[0]
print(f"Counts for the meas output register: {pub_result.data.meas.get_counts()}")


As far as I can tell, your code is the correct way to run a Qiskit >= 1.0 program. The philosophy Qiskit wants to enforce is that of Qiskit patterns:

So, this part of your code corresponds to the mapping between the problem and the circuits and operators:
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.measure_all()
print(qc.draw())

You then optimize it for target hardware using generate_preset_pass_manager:
backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False)
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=1)
isa_circuit = pm.run(qc)

You execute it on quantum hardware:
sampler = Sampler(mode=backend)
sampler.options.default_shots = 100000
job = sampler.run([isa_circuit])

And finally you post-process the results:
pub_result = job.result()[0]
print(f"Counts for the meas output register: {pub_result.data.meas.get_counts()}")

So, everything looks fine here. Concerning your questions:

Although the code is hopefully working fine, it has two run, which is kind of strange

The first one is used to transpile the circuit. On that regard:

Also, there is something new called generate_preset_pass_manager. Is this the same as transpile in previous versions?

Kind of. The way you're using it, it totally is. Basically, this function allows you to have more control on the process of transpilation by specifying options at each stage of it. I encourage you to read this IBM Quantum Challenge notebook to learn more about it.
The takeaway is that if you leave everything be default except the backend and the optimization level, it behaves like the former transpile function.
The second run method is that of the Sampler. On that regard:

Also, there is something new called a sampler. Is this sampler the same as  backend.run in previous versions?

Though I think the API slightly changed (notably in the way you retrieve the results), the functionality is the same yes. The Sampler simply takes a list of ISA circuits (i.e. transpiled ones) and a bunch of options and samples from the resulting output distribution in the computational basis. Sampler is one of the two Qiskit primitives, the other one being the Estimator. You can read more about them here.
The takeaway is that you can use the Sampler similarly to how you were using backend.run previously.

Thank you @TristanNemoz for great help.
